# InvalidArgument with HTML Table's insertBefore method

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, insertion

I think I know this is an IE bug ...
I need to add new row to an HTML table at the exact position.
(don't want insertRow(index) cuz this looks like gonna be better for some other reasons)

```
function AddNewItem(td) {   ///td comes from button at the HTML code, <input ... onclick="AddNewItem(this.parentNode)"
  var grid = GetGrid();
  var itemIndex = $(td.parentNode).attr('index');
  ///alert(itemIndex + "'e eklenecek");
  var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
      var td1 = document.createElement('td');$(td1).addClass('td');
      var td2 = document.createElement('td');$(td2).addClass('td text r');
      var td3 = document.createElement('td');$(td3).addClass('td text r');
      var td4 = document.createElement('td');$(td4).addClass('td text r');
  $(newRow).append(td1);$(newRow).append(td2);$(newRow).append(td3);$(newRow).append(td4);

  grid.insertBefore(newRow, td.parentNode); ///THIS GIVES AN INVALIDARGUMENT error .. Any solutions will be appreciated :)
}


function GetGrid() {
 var grid = document.getElementById("MasterTableView");
 return grid;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on why you are mixing normal DOM and jQuery? And what's wrong with insertRow?

Comment: I should use jquery's create instead of document.Create and such? 
I don't know, I do stuff with what I know best. I am not the best JS ninja afterall :)

Comment: insertRow want an index, and adds an empty row. Than after I have to find that empty row and ad TD's in it .. i thought it will be ugly in the first place ... I should use insertRow right? .. I should go and do that

Comment: What do you mean with "find that empty row"? `insertRow` returns a reference to the created row. You should either use all jQuery, or all DOM (with insertRow). Don't mix it up.

Comment: didn't know that it returned a reference. and why not mix them up :)

Comment: Is this question still open, or are you going to use `insertRow`?  If it's still open, what's giving you the invalid argument error -- `newRow` or `td.parentNode`?  If it's `td.parentNode`, then can you provide a sample of what's being passed in to this function?

Comment: How are you calling `AddNewItem`?

Answer (score 0):

My ***guess*** is that `td.parentNode` is not a child element of `grid`. Take a look at the [W3C specification for insertBefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-952280727) to make sure that you are calling the method with valid parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you're passing in an invalid argument to `AddNewItem`, that (in IE, at least) it's not a `td` element like you think.

Comment: don't worry .. it is that td like I think :)
it gives the innerHTML and plus the whole thing works now